# Create common setup while using SQLite 32 bit and 64 bit

Tags: .net, sqlite, installation, 64-bit, 32-bit

My client has an existing application created in .NET which uses SQLite. They have created a separate code base and created two different set ups where one uses 32-bit SQLite for 32 bit OS and the other uses 64-bit SQLite for 64 bit OS. They ship this as a product in CD so their requirement now is to merge both setups so that it can be provided in a single CD and the cost of maintenance and maintaining two builds is reduced.

I do not know if there is any way out here as I am new to this area. Can anybody help?

Answer (score 1):

Mixed 32/64-bit installers are supported by multiple commercial setup authoring tools. Here is a list which can get you started:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_installation_software

I recommend Advanced Installer or InstallShield.

The general approach is to add both 32-bit and 64-bit elements into your installer and condition them based on the target machine. The setup tool also uses an internal mechanism to automatically detect 32-bit and 64-bit machines and adjust the installation accordingly.

Comment: Thanks Cosmin Pirvu for answering. However, I am bit confused in build creation. On which machine should I create a build.. 32/64 bit? Which SQLLite assembly should I refer in the code... 32/64 bit? Instead of purchasing these tools (my client won't agree) is there any way/location where I can write a code which can dynamically load appropriate SQLLite version depending on system bitness?